# Hudson + CVS headaches

Tags: .net, cvs, hudson, tortoisecvs

I'm trying to configure my Hudson server to retrieve code from a CVS repository, but so far it's been a pretty frustrating experience.

My setup is Hudson 1.310 running as a system service, CVSNT latest version on the server, TortoiseCVS 1.10.10.

I'm getting "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" all the time, even if I open the password agent as a system process with the trick suggested in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/articles/271063.aspx.

I really don't know where to look for more info regarding this problem, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem by doing a manual cvs login on the command line as the system account. You might want to try that.